# spring 3 webClient mock server

Tags: spring-webclient, reactor-netty

i'am using a service that wraps a webClient of spring and I want to test it , mock a server and set http call expectations and mock responses .
i have the following code :

this service that behind the scene make an http call with webClient :

```
listener = new listener(webClient, conf);
```

and I want to do the equivalent of this code I used to use in RestTemplate :

```
MockRestServiceServer server = MockRestServiceServer.bindTo(listener.getWebClient()).build();
    server.expect(once(), requestTo("http://localhost:8080/tise"))
            .andExpect(method(HttpMethod.POST))
            .andRespond(withBadRequest());
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

This was originally considered by the Spring Framework team when the `WebClient` was first introduced.

Given the effort required to create and maintain such an arrangement, and the fact that there are several alternatives that work well (like OkHttp MockWebServer or WireMock), [the team decided to decline this enhancement](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/19852). [This is mentioned in the reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/web/webflux-webclient/client-testing.html).